# Add file name as a column in each dataframe in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, mutate

I am attempting to add a new column to each dataframe in a list of 131 dataframes, the content of this new column being the name of the file of the original data frame. Here are the steps I have completed so far, after which I have struggled:

```
#Libraries:
library(dplyr)


#Making a list of all files in my working directory that begin with "i_":

list_of_files <- list.files(pattern = "i_")

#Creating a list of those dataframes, reading them in as csvs:

my_data <- lapply(list_of_files, read.csv)

#I have then tried to mutate across these dataframes, to no avail, with very low quality code:

datamap <- lapply(my_data, ~ .x %>% 
      mutate(file_title = file_id()))
```

Does anyone know how to complete this task?

Comment: I think you mean `map(my_data, ~ .x ...)`, because `lapply` does not understand `~`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
my_data <- imap(my_data, ~ .x %>% mutate(file_title = .y))
```

The `imap()` function defines two automatic variables: `.x`, which is the regular element of `my_data`, while `.y` is the corresponding name of the element in `my_data`.

Comment: This works great, as long as I adjust from lapply() to sapply()!

Comment: Huh, I think sapply should not work in your case. It would be much easier if you had a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).